# How to stop google speech-to-text streaming node js

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text

I use google speech to text API to transcript voice to text. I am trying to terminate this service when we hit the is_final=True... or after a certain number of seconds. I can't seem to find anything in the node js documentation on how to do this, but I was able to find it in python. 
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.StreamingRecognitionConfig

How would I do this in Node?

Comment: did you found a solution for this i am also stuck in this places i can record and convert to text everything only problem is i can't stop streaming until i need so it will increase google billings

Comment: I can't remember exactly... but I think I ended up setting the google transcribe instance to false and just re-initilazing it

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. now i have check in API index.js there are function and called stop, pause even i can call them like this recorder.record().stop() but it's giving me the error process.kill("SIGNSTP") invalid still not found proper solution